# How to replace all sub strings ending with marker in scala?

Tags: regex, scala

I have path containing **key=value**, like:

```
hdfs://0.0.0.0:9000/tmp/test/abc=value1/xyz=value2/pqr=value3
```

I want to remove **key=** parts from this path.

So output will look like:

```
hdfs://0.0.0.0:9000/tmp/test/value1/value2/value3
```

So how to do this in Scala?

Comment: could you give an example how should be the output like?

Comment: @MahmoudHanafy I have updated question. Please help.

Comment: Why downvotes? I could not understand reason for downvotes.

Comment: StackOverflow rewards effort. Your question doesn't indicate that you've done any research. It is helpful to include what you've already tried. Code that doesn't work demonstrates where your approach/understanding can be addressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val path = "/tmp/test/abc=value1/xyz=value1/pqr=value1"

val res = "/[^/]+=".r.replaceAllIn(path, "/")
//res: String = /tmp/test/value1/value1/value1
```

- `/` - find a slash
- `[^/]+` - followed by some number of non-slash characters
- `=` - followed by an equals
- remove everything but the slash